# Should I submit an article to a not-yet-indexed WOS journal, hoping that it will be indexed later?

Tags: publications, impact-factor

I am planning to submit an article to an unindexed WOS journal. However, I think that since this journal in the WOS journal list, it will market itself one way or another and let's say in a few years it may be indexed and will have a great impact factor.

There are some key considerations:

- the journal's publisher is well known UK publishing company
- the publication cost is free
- the volumes are published two times per year.
- my field is computer and information security.

My question: Is it worth considering to publish with the long-term goals that the journal will rise (here the barrier to enter is not very difficult, but I think it's a bit lower than for already-known journals) or is it better to stick with the already established journals with good impact factors?

Comment: why don't you mention the name of this secret journal?

Comment: Its not the secret, but to avoid the the so-called "marketing purposes" i can say its "taylors and francis" journal

Comment: It seems to me that this depends on what country you're in (or plan to be in) and probably also on your employer. The main issue, in my opinion, is (1) whether anyone will care about indexing and impact factors and (2) if so, then whether the journal you're considering will meet that anyone's criteria by the time they care.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thank you for the feedback. I am Ph.D. student and also in academia. You are right, it depends on the timeframe and given that this is WOS journal from the well-known publisher, there are high odds that the  journal will be indexed in next 1 or 2 years. You are right about "where I am planning to be"

Comment: Nobody is going to care about which journal you choose, because nobody in CS reads journal papers.

Comment: @JeffE it is not like that, since in order to maintain the status of the university, academicians have to publish their researches to the rated journals on the regular basis. Another thing, the Ph.D. considers publishing the research also in the rated journals. The executives care much where the paper is published

Comment: @mydreamadsl Not at my university, we don’t.

Comment: @JeffE Unfortunately, there seem to be not only universities but whole countries whose governments use ratings of journals to assess the quality of research.

Comment: Fair point. And if you live in such a country, the answer to this question is clear: Don't risk it. Do the minimum work required to definitively check off the stupid bureaucratic requirement and move on.

Comment: @JeffE Thank you. This is silly, but it is true. Govs pursuing the ranked journal to promote academia and themselves on the international arena. Thank you. I will keep your considerations in mind